# Why is same key cookie is set twice with different values?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am setting a loggedIn cookie when user logins.

It is set using -
`` document.cookie = `token=${data.data.token}; path=/;} ``

Now my chrome dev tools shows:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD0xC.png)
[image: Chrome Dev Tools Appliation > Cookies]

And when I do `document.cookie` it returns two cookies
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgN5c.png)
[image: document.cookie returns two cookies]

I have only set the cookie which is shown in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD0xC.png) but not [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgN5c.png) but this still shows up.

I tried refreshing the page, force clearing all the cookies but didn't worked.
One more intersting thing about it is that the cookie in pic 2 i.ie., token=540c13d-... does not change on relogin or changing login accounts.

What might be the reason for such a behaviour?

Comment: What is `data.data.token`?

Comment: This is what my backend API returns as a token

Comment: You're setting the cookie with `path=/`. If there's a cookie for a subdirectory, it will take precedence.

Comment: I suspect that there's another part of the code (maybe some third-party library) that is setting the other token, not this line. What happens if you rename the cookie to some other name instead of `token` (e.g. document.cookie = `mytoken=${data.data.token}; path=/;}`

Comment: Renaming the cookie does not create duplicate for the renamed_key. Also refreshing the page somehow clears the auto_generated cookie now.